# WSO2 get SAML attributes of different entries in Active Directory

Tags: wso2, saml-2.0

I maybe have a stupied question concerning WSO2 and SAML- attributes.
I have written a Service Provider which made it possible to login via WSO2. 
With login- response / authentication- response, I get all SAML- Attributes which are defined in WSO2 as claims (attributes came from Active Directory)

If logged in, with an "org.opensaml.saml2.core.AuthnRequest", die SAML Attributes can be retrieved from WSO2 once again of the logged in user - for any reason.

This all works fine.

Now, I would need attributes of other persons (not the logged in one) in the Active Directory.

Therefore my question would be if it is possible to retrieve attributes of different persons than the logged in one from Active Directory over WSO2 and SAML without login of that different persons?

The reason is, that I have different AD- groups (each contains different person information) and I will show the attributes of the persons in my Service Provider.

Thanks a lot for your answers and help.

All the best and thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. You can use the SOAP service https://`host:port`/services/RemoteUserStoreManagerService

Answer (score 0):

HideAdminServiceWSDLs must be set to false - thanks a lot!!